# Suite8, Oracle, Fidelio XML interface get Accompany guest details

Tags: c#, suite

I would like to use xml interface for Suite8 to get the details for accompany guest with age, nationality

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fidelio
    xmlns="V8XMLInterface"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="V8XMLInterfacec:\duffy\Specifications\XMLInterface\FidelioXML.xsd" Version="1.1.0">
    <request ID="Sys2"  UserName="xml" assword="xml">
        <query Name="ResRequest1" ReqType="Reservation">
            <conditions>
                <condition name="GuestNum" operation="eq" xsi:type="ReservationConditionType">649283</condition>
            </conditions>
            <fields>
                <field name="ProfileID"/>
                <field name="GuestFirstname"/>
                <field name="GuestName"/>
                <field name="GuestArrival"/>
                <field name="GuestDeparture"/>
                <field name="RoomNum"/>
                <field name="AccompanyingGuests"></field>
                <field name="Age"/>
                <field name="Childs"></field>
            </fields>
        </query>
    </request>
</fidelio>
```

Comment: Could you maybe reformat the code a bit? Can you show what you already tried?

Comment: Can you explain further ? What is the problem that you're facing ?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Oracle's XML Interface Specification for Hospitality Suite8](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/F17277_01/docs/F17639-02.pdf), this can be done like so:

### Perform a request of type `Reservation`

<sup>The above mentioned document gives you comprehensive information on how this is done in detail.

The following examples were using a german locale.</sup>

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fidelio Version="1.0.0">
    <request ID="1" UserName="SomeUser" Password="SomePassword">
        <query ReqType="Reservation">
            <conditions>
                <condition name="GuestArrival" operation="eq">30.03.2022</condition>
                <link operator="AND">
                    <condition>
                        <condition name="RoomNum" operation="eq">5555</condition>
                    </condition>
                </link>
            </conditions>
            <fields>
                <field name="AccompanyingGuests"/>
                <field name="RoomNum"/>
                <field name="GuestArrival"/>
            </fields>
        </query>
    </request>
</fidelio>
```

The response could look like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fidelio Version="1.0.0">
  <response ID="1" Status="OK">
    <queryResponse>
      <rows>
        <row>
          <fields>
            <field name="GuestArrival">30.03.2022 19:32:34</field>
            <field name="RoomNum">5555</field>
            <field name="AccompanyingGuest" name1="Lady" name2="" name3="Some" BedGuestNum="47014">201362</field>
          </fields>
        </row>
      </rows>
    </queryResponse>
  </response>
</fidelio>
```

The response in the `AccompanyingGuest` field only contains the attributes `name1`, `name2`, `name3` and `BedGuestNum`. In order to get the needed data, you'll have to...

### Post another request, this time of type `Profile`

Use the (not so obvious) `ProfileID` from the previous answer

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fidelio Version="1.0.0">
    <request ID="1" UserName="SomeUser" Password="SomePassword">
        <query ReqType="Profile">
            <conditions>
                <condition name="ProfileID" operation="eq">201362</condition>
            </conditions>
            <fields>
                <field name="GuestFirstname"/>
                <field name="GuestName"/>
                <field name="Birthday"/>
                <field name="Gender"/>
                <field name="NationalityISO2"/>
                <field name="NationalityISO3"/>
                <field name="CountryISO2"/>
                <field name="CountryISO3"/>
             </fields>
        </query>
    </request>
</fidelio>
```

The response could look like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fidelio Version="1.0.0">
  <response ID="1" Status="OK">
    <queryResponse>
      <rows>
        <row>
          <fields>
            <field name="GuestFirstname">Some</field>
            <field name="GuestName">Lady</field>
            <field name="Birthday">01.10.1995</field>
            <field name="Gender">F</field>
            <field name="CountryISO2">DE</field>
            <field name="CountryISO3">DEU</field>
            <field name="NationalityISO2"/>
            <field name="NationalityISO3"/>
          </fields>
        </row>
      </rows>
    </queryResponse>
  </response>
</fidelio>
```

The values for `NationalityISO2` and `NationalityISO2` weren't entered for that person, and are hence emtpy.